# How to determine break points to define ranges of cells - VBA BEGINNER

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a program that will calculate an average using a range of cells that are between variables which are defined as BREAK_A, BREAK_B, and BREAK_C - in which the range between these break points will vary depending on user entry - therefore the range to calculate the average will vary.

One thing to note, A1 and A10 can never be a location for a break point.

Example Excel Spreadsheet:

```
A1 = 11
A2 = 24
A3 = 15
A4 = BREAK_C
A5 = 17
A6 = BREAK_B
A7 = 6
A8 = 33
A9 = BREAK_A
A10 = 12
```

Attempt With Some Pseudo-Code:

```
Public Sub Sort()

DIM BREAK_A AS NUM
DIM BREAK_B AS NUM
DIM BREAK_C AS NUM

DIM RANGE1 AS VARIANT
DIM RANGE2 AS VARIANT
DIM RANGE3 AS VARIANT
DIM FULL_RANGE AS VARIANT

 FIND CELL NUMBERS OF(BREAK_A, BREAK_B, BREAK_C) 
 SORT CELL NUMBERS IN ASCENDING ORDER

RANGE1 = "A1: LOWEST CELL NUMBER OF BREAK"
RANGE2 = "LOWEST CELL NUMBER OF BREAK +1 : NEXT HIGHEST CELL NUMBER OF BREAK"
RANGE3 = "NEXT HIGHEST CELL NUMBER OF BREAK +1 : END"
```

My problem is the BREAK points will populate different cell locations depending on user entry. I would like to write a program that defines the range of cells of which to calculate an average on - depending on where the break points are.

ALSO, sometimes a BREAK may not exist - so I cannot always use BREAK_A, BREAK_B, BREAK_C as end points to my range, since you could have a situation where only be BREAK_A and BREAK_C should be considered, and BREAK_B does not exist.

For this example, I want to make the calculation =AVG(A1:A3, A5, A7:A8, A10)

Any help in generating ideas would be greatly appreciated. I am new to VBA and haven't been able to solve this problem for several days now..

Comment: so you want to average every cell that does not conatian `BREAK_?`?  The worksheet function Average will ignore text on its own: `=AVERAGE(A1:A10)` Which will return 16.857.  Or do you want 4 different averages based on the breaks?

Comment: @ScottCraner I need one average of all the numbers besides the BREAKS - however the break values are also numbers that are defined by the user. I should have made that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code

```
Sub Test()

lstrng = ActiveSheet.Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row
Startrng = 1
For i = 1 To lstrng


    If Range("A" & i).Value = "Break" Then
        Endrng = i - 1
        Range("A" & i).Value =  WorksheetFunction.Average(Range(Cells(Startrng, 1), Cells(Endrng, 1)))
        Startrng = i + 1
    End If

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I should have made it more clear that BREAK was just to demonstrate what I was trying to accomplish. The BREAK variables are actually numbers defined by the user, so it will not appear as BREAK in the spreadsheet, but rather a number. However these BREAK values are declared as variables.

Comment: Could I change this statement to:  If Range("A" & i).Value = "Break1" or "Break2" etc?